# Регулярное выражение по удалению "/" в конце

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть переменная, в которой хранится список сайтов:

```
$urls = 'https://yandex.ru/
https://google.ru/';
```

Нужно с помощью `preg_replace` в PHP удалить у всех сайтов в конце **/**.

На данный момент мой код работает неправильно и удаляет **/** только у последнего сайта.

```
echo preg_replace('/\/$/', '', $urls);
```

Результат:

```
https://yandex.ru/
https://google.ru
```

Необходимо так:

```
https://yandex.ru
https://google.ru
```

Comment: а обязательно с помощью preg_replace? Если бы я не умел пользоваться регулярками, то делал бы через explode и rtrim()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В PHP это будет так:

```php
$urls = 'https://yandex.ru/
https://google.ru/';

echo preg_replace('/\/$/m', '', $urls);
```